# Cannot use variables to change css property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background-color of an element  by clicking on a button. In 2 implementations of javascript, I am storing slightly different values in the same variable, and using the variables to change the background-color. I expect both implementations to work, but only one works. Here are the details.

In HTML, I have a `<div id="foo">Lorem</div>` element and a `<button id="button">Click</button>` element.

I have 2 different codes for JavaScript. The first one is:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var x = document.getElementById("foo").style;

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    x.backgroundColor="red";
});
```

The second one is:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var x = document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor;

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    x="red";
});
```

The first one works, but the second one does not. The only difference between the two code snippets is in the first one, the variable x **did not** include `backgroundColor` and the background color of x was changed using `x.backgroundColor="red";`. In the second one, the variable x **did** include `backgroundColor` and the color was changed(tried to change) using `x="red";`.

Why does the first way work, but the second way does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you are pointing `x` at the `style` object that exists for the `foo` component. When you assign a string to `x.backgroundColor`, you are effectively assigning a string to `document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor` since `x` and `style` point to the same object in memory.

In the second example, you are simply assigning the `style.backgroundColor` string to `x`. You then assign a new string to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

All that second attempt does is reassign `x` away from the current `backgroundColor` property value to the value of `red`. It's no different than this:

```js
var x = 10;
x = 20;
console.log(x); // 20
```

In other words, `x` is not a reference to the `backgroundColor` ***property***, it's a reference to the ***value*** stored in that property, so let's say the original value of the property was "Yellow", then `x` would be storing the string `Yellow`, it's not a reference to where that value came from - - only the value itself. **So, when you change it, you aren't doing anything to the `backgroundColor` property, you are just changing the value of `x` from "Yellow" to "Red".**

You can store the value you'd like to assign to `backgroundColor` as shown below:

```js
// x doesn't store a reference to the object property. It stores 
// the VALUE of the property at this moment in time.
var x = document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor;

var color = "green";

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

  console.log("Original color of element: " + x);
   
  x = "red";  // All this does is make x point away from it's previous value
  
  console.log("New value of 'x': " + x);
    
  // You need a statement that assigns a new value to the property
  document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor = color;
  
  console.log("New color of element: " + document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor);
});
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="background-color:orange;">Lorem</div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: @LettuceBerg Please don't ever edit someone's code that they are showing just because you would write it differently. There's no reason to bring `const` into the discussion. The OP isn't using it and it doesn't change the behavior of the code here at all. Use your edit privilege wisely. If you believe the code should be changed, just add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.getElementById("foo").style;
```

in this example, x is a style object, like:

```
{
  padding: 0;
  backgroundColor: blue; 
}
```

while in the second example, x is actually a string, and in the callback function, x only is assigned with new string.

you can console.log(x) to see the differences of these two "x"s.